# special symbol avoid in sssis

Tags: ssis

I have small doubt in ssis. please tell me how to solve this issue

source table :emp   id ,name  having datatype varchar(30),sal money

```
             id|  name |  sal 
             1 |  abc   |100
            ,2"|  def   |2500
             3 |  ",rac"|1400
             4 |  ven   |200
           "5",|  jai   |100
             10|  ha    |50
```

when we load this data into target table that time we need to load correct data

target table datatypes also id,name having dataype varchar(30),sal money

target table  data want look like below

target table : emptarg

```
              id   |  name  | sal
              1   |  abc   |100
              4   | ven    |200
              10  |  ha    | 50
```

and errore records load into separate table

```
     error table:emperror 
                           id  | name   | sal
                           ,2" |  def   |2500
                            3  |  ",rac"|1400
                           "5",|  jai   |100
```

when source data having special symoble that records  need to send error  table .how to write condition in conditional split and any other ways.

Comment: Do you have a full list of these special symbols?

Comment: all data symbol's Having like    ,"!@#$%^*( .  what ever having this symboles that data we need to separte it. Thanks

Comment: Meaning only these symbols - "!@#$%^*( ?

Comment: what every having  this symbols  that data comes wrong data so we need to separeate that data which are having  this symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to match multiple characters, I'd suggest the below approach;

1. Create a Script Transform.
2. Create necessary output columns corresponding to input columns from source table. Add one more output column of `bool` type called `IsValid`.
3. In the `ProcessInputRow` method of script, use pattern matching to check that `id` column contains only numbers and `name` column contains only letters. If this is not the case, set `IsValid` to `false`.

   ```
   using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

   ...

   public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
    {
      bool isValid = true;

      ...

      public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
       {
        if (Regex.IsMatch(Row.id, @"^[0-9]+$") && Regex.IsMatch(Row.name, @"^[a-zA-Z]+$"))
         {
           Row.derivedid = int.Parse(Row.id);
           Row.derivedname = Row.name;           
         }
        else
         {            
           isValid = false;
         }         

         Row.IsValid = isValid; 
       }

   }
   ```
4. Next add a `Conditional Split` transform, and depending on whether `IsValid` is true or false, redirect the rows to respective destinations.

Comment: when i use this script all records treat (isvalid columns) as false.its not satisfy for our condition.even good rows also goes to false condition.plz  see given above sample source data .if that records work full then i will do any remain symbols came. thanks

Comment: Sorry I missed the initialisation to true. Please try now.

Comment: same result only came.previous and now.its not comeing our exactely result.Thanks

Comment: SELECT [name]
  FROM [test].[dbo].[nametest] where name   like  '[a-zA-Z]%' or name  like '%"%' or name  like '%,%' that time i get unmatched records.but this logic not good way .we required good and bad records. is it possible to implement this logic in conditional split

Comment: Hi why we  take Row.derivedid = int.Parse(Row.id);
        Row.derivedname = Row.name;  we are not declare any where  Row.derivedid and derivedname. its not working to follow same script.plz can u tell me how to avoid this issue.

Comment: These are my 'derived' columns that belong to `Output0` of the script transform. You need to add these 2 columns to that Output first. I forgot to set the type for `id` to numeric, so had to parse it as `int`, but it is not necessary if `id` is already an `int`.

Comment: i done to add required fields name in output0 then  i tried given dataype either varchar or boolean (two cases i tested)but still given wrong.please suggest me where i done mistick.

Comment: Please add all the relevant code and tasks screenshots/links in your question, instead of updating bit by bit in comments. Without actually seeing what you did, I can't help figure out what could have gone wrong.